# How to prevent another div from scrolling when i am scrolling in the navigationbar phone

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, mobile

I am building an app in phonegap, but i am encountering a bug that, if I scrolled to the bottom of the navigationbar, my body wrap starts scrolling.

This is an example:

```
<body>
    <nav id="navbar-header">
         <div class="navbar-header"></div> //navbar in top of the page, not relevant probarly
         <div class="header-inner">
               <div id="navbar">
                     <ul>
                           <li>list with pages, on some devices scrollable, on some not.</li>
                           <li>some of it is dynamically loaded.</li>
                     </ul>
                     <div>lot of elements that make it scrollable</div
               </div>
         </div>
     </nav>
     <div id='wrap'>
          <div class="overlay">is display:block if the navbar is shown, else it is display:none</div>
          <div id='pageContext'>lot of dynamic in here, so scrollable most of the times</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#navbar-header {
height: 70px;
}

#navbar {
position: relative;
width: 225px!important;
height: auto;
min-height: 100vh;
float: right;
padding: 0;
margin-right: -225px; //width is static, this is set to 0 with animation if the navbar slides in.
margin-top: 10px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0.25;
z-index: 10;
background-color: black;
background-size: contain;
display: none;
}
```

and the javascript i currently use:
the code that is //commented out is other not properly working solutions but i keep them in this snippet in case of.

```
$(function(){
    var menuBtnBusy = false;
    $('#menubtn').click(function(){ 
        if( !menuBtnBusy ) {
            menuBtnBusy = true;
            var $this = $(this);

            if( $this.attr('aria-expanded') === "false" ) {
                $('#navbar').animate({'margin-right':'0px'}, 600, function() {
                    $this.attr('aria-expanded', "true");
                    menuBtnBusy = false;
                    // $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
                });
                $('.overlay').css('display','block');
                $('.overlay').css('opacity',0.25);
                // var totalHeight=$(window).height()-70;//$('#navbar-header').height();
                // previousYoffset=window.scrollY;
                // $('#homepage-wrapper').css('max-height',totalHeight+'px');
                // $('#homepage-wrapper').css('overflow','hidden');
            }
            else {
                $('.overlay').css('display','none');
                $('.overlay').css('opacity',0);
                $('#navbar').animate({"margin-right":"-225px"}, 600, function() {
                    $this.attr('aria-expanded', "false");
                    menuBtnBusy = false;
                    // $('body').css('overflow','visible');

                    $('#navbar ul').show();
                    $('#navbar .region-wrap').hide();
                });
                // $('#homepage-wrapper').css('max-height','none');
                // $('#homepage-wrapper').css('overflow','visible');
                // window.scroll(0,previousYoffset);
                // previousYoffset=0;
            }
        }
    });     
    $('.overlay').on("click", function(e) {
        if (!menuBtnBusy) {
            menuBtnBusy = true;
            if ( $('#menubtn').attr('aria-expanded') === "true" ) {
                if (e.target.id != '#navbar' && $(e.target).parent('#navbar').length == 0) {
                    $('.overlay').css('display','none');
                    $('.overlay').css('opacity',0);
                    $('#navbar').animate({"margin-right":"-225px"},600,function() {
                        $('#menubtn').attr('aria-expanded', "false");
                        menuBtnBusy = false;
                        // $('body').css('overflow','visible'); 
                        $('#navbar ul').show();
                        $('#navbar .region-wrap').hide();


                    });     
                    // $('#homepage-wrapper').css('max-height','none');
                    // $('#homepage-wrapper').css('overflow','visible');    
                    // window.scroll(0,previousYoffset);
                    // previousYoffset=0;                   
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Does anyone know how i am able to prevent the scrolling of the body when the navigationbar is opened?

I have tried quite a lot of things, like temporarily setting the wrap height to 100% and overflow hidden, but that solution makes the page jump to the top each time i open the navigationbar.

So i do not want the body to jump at all when opening the navigationbar.

One thought that came in my mind is that when scrolling, getting if the nearest element is the navbar or the body behind but i have totaly no clue if this is possible, and maybe there are smarter ideas.

[image of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsVoo.png)

Comment: Can you show us the working form.

Comment: okay i add i screenshot